# Remove sudo/doas from tmux pane name

Tags: linux, tmux

So the situation, if I run for instance this command (`doas` is an alternative to `sudo`):

```
doas emaint sync
```

`tmux` changes the pane name to say `doas`, which albeit correct, is not really useful because the 'meat' is `emaint` rather than `doas`.

Is it possible to configure `tmux` in a way that rather than having `sudo` (or in my case, `doas`) appearing as the pane name, it uses the command after `sudo`/`doas` instead? Or, in other words, to make it *automatically* show (in the above case) `emaint` instead?

(Key word is "automatically"; I don't want to keep renaming the pane every time.)